# UIView frame origin x animation with bounce effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiview

I have managed to get my UIView to animate when moving its frame.origin.x from x to x-200; however, when frame.origin.x reaches x-200, I'd like it to bounce a little bit back and forth.

Anyone any tips as to how I should go about doing this?
thanks

```
int targetX = 200;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

myView.frame = CGRectMake(targetX, 0, [myView frame].size.width, [myView frame].size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that you'll need to do a path animation.  See: http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/04/26/core-animation-on-the-iphone/ for a simple tutorial on doing that.

The basic animation just animates between one point and another with some velocity changes (ease-in, ease-out).  Path animation can do curves, direction changes, etc.

Comment: Yep, `CAKeyframeAnimation` is the way to go.

Comment: That link is down. That's y it's a good practice to copy some of code here too.

Comment: That link is back up now. The code samples in that link are large and there  didn't seem to be a way to refine it to a manageable snippet.